# Prove that $\int_{0}^{1}\!\!\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}\mathrm dy\mathrm dx = 0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How to integrate $$\int_{0}^{1}\!\!\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}\mathrm dy\mathrm dx$$
I tried converting it into polar coordinates but got stuck on the limits. And here's my other approach[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bc8K.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried ? Where are you stuck ? [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and [How to ask a good question ?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: Welcome to MSE community @Anirudh. What is your attempt? What did you try??

Comment: First of all show your approach @Anirudh.

Comment: For those who have downvoted this comment, I do not feel it is appropriate to do so. @Anirudh is a new contributor, and it can be very soul-crushing if one of your first few questions gets downvoted by at least 3 people. I know this post does not fit Math SE guidelines, but we should kindly redirect the poster to links suck as those mentioned in the comments above. For the poster, please make appropriate changes. But for those who have downvoted, I'm not asking you to upvote, but instead of blindly costing yourself and others' reputation, it would be better to kindly redirect to the links.

Comment: Did not downvote, but you do not lose reputation when downvoting a question, only an answer. Right?

Comment: Can someone please give the answer using polar coordinates and a comprehensible reason for each step? I don't understand how do you get the limit values and what is the region of integration.

Comment: The integrand is antisymmetric in $x$ and $y$

Comment: @Anirudh Please improve your post first: read the 3 first comments above , and/or [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\begin{array}\\
I
&=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}\mathrm dy\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\mathrm dy\mathrm dx-\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}\mathrm dy\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\mathrm dy\mathrm dx-\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy
\quad\text{(reversing order of integration in second integral)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\mathrm dy\mathrm dx-\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\mathrm dy\mathrm dx
\quad\text{(swapping x and y)}\\
&=0\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: This question goes against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

The set-up in polar coordinates

$x = r\cos \theta\\
y=r\sin \theta\\
dy\ dx = r\ dr\ d\theta$

Limits:

The region is bound by the line $x = 1$ when $\theta\in[0,\frac \pi 4)$ and $y=1$ when $\theta\in[\frac {\pi}{4},\frac {\pi}{2}]$

$x=1$
$r\cos\theta = 1\\
r=\sec\theta$

$y=1$
$r\sin\theta = 1\\
r=\csc\theta$

$\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{4}}\int_0^{\sec\theta} \frac {r^2\cos^2\theta - r^2\sin^2 \theta}{r^2\cos^2\theta + r^2\sin^2\theta} (r\ dr\ d\theta) + \int_{\frac {\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{\csc\theta} \frac {r^2\cos^2\theta - r^2\sin^2 \theta}{r^2\cos^2\theta + r^2\sin^2\theta} (r\ dr\ d\theta)$

Comment: This question goes against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.